# Scenekit write exits without error

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I'm trying to store my scenekit scene (ideally to Firebase but I don't think that's possible?). Using the following from what little seems to be in the documentation - I simply get **1.0 returned as progress** (complete) and **nil for the error**.

```
@IBOutlet weak var sceneView: ARSCNView!
let scene = SCNScene()
sceneView.scene = scene

sceneView.scene.write(to: URL(string: "http://foo.com")!, options: nil, delegate: nil) { (totalProgress, error, stop) in
        print("Progress \(totalProgress) Error: \(String(describing: error))")
    }
```

The url is obviously a dummy one and I'd expect it to error on that at least? When I use a proper Firebase storage url nothing is stored and I get the same feedback. Does anybody have a working swift 3 (pref) example?

Thanks

Comment: First of all, what are `sceneView` and `scene` above (I can guess, but best not to assume), and what is providing the `write` functionality?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using ARKit and everything is working correctly for that, this is just a new feature I'm trying to add, I'll update my question to show the code for scene and sceneView. Write is coming from here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscene/1523577-write

Comment: Are you trying to save to Firebase Storage?  I'm going to bet the problem lies in the Firebase domain.

Comment: In the meantime, try writing to a local file and see if that presents the same problem.

Comment: I tried locally earlier, but I will try again as suggested. This is running on an iPhone so are you suggesting to the phones filesystem or via ngrok to localhost on my Mac? Cheers

Comment: Writing to FileManager gives the same response. Will keep trying. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like SceneKit fails to properly surface the error, but the return value should be correct:

```
  let success = sceneView.scene.write(to: URL(string: "http://foo.com")!, options: nil, delegate: nil) { (totalProgress, error, stop) in
        print("Progress \(totalProgress) Error: \(String(describing: error))")
    }
    print("Success: \(success)")
```

> Progress 1.0 Error: nil
>
> Success: false

To get a sense of what's failing you can first create the SceneKit document and then try to save it:

```
    let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: sceneView.scene)
    do {
        try data.write(to: URL(string: "http://foo.com")!)
    } catch let error {
        print("Error: \(String(describing: error))")
    }
```

> Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=518 "The file couldn’t be saved because URL type http isn’t supported." UserInfo={NSURL=http://foo.com}

Comment: Great, I'll try that. End of the day here so may be later tonight or first thing in the morning. Thanks for the pointer, I'll let you know. Cheers

Comment: That got me over the hurdle. I've yet to pull the created file back in but I can see it stored if I use the second option of creating the scene file then writing to location. I still had false positives with the first snippet so have abandoned that approach for now. Many thanks, will mark this as the answer.

Comment: The first version should also work. Make sure you provide a local file path, with a filename and extension.